# How to use Interface to overcome multiple if, else

Tags: php

NOTE: I have added only snippets of my code.

I have to validate Partner user while they register and if the validation passes then we create a plan for them else we treat them as a normal user and won't create a plan for them.

```
public function givePlan(Request $request){
    /* Validation Code Goes Here */
    try{
        $data       = $request->all();
        /*Get partner details*/
        $partner    = $this->getPartnerDetailsByUniqueId($data['partner_id']);
        /** Validate the user details */
        $this->validateUser($partner, $data['phone']);
        /* Rest of the code */
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        /* 400 handle the exception */
    }
}

protected function validateUser($partner, $phone){
    $partnerObj = new ValidatePartner();
    if($partner == 'partner1'){
        $partnerObj->validatePartner1($phone);
        /* rest of the code */
    }else if($partner == 'partner2'){
        $partnerObj->validatePartner2($phone);
        /* rest of the code */
    }else if($partner == 'partner3'){
        $partnerObj->validatePartner3($phone);
        /* rest of the code */
    }
}
```

The problem over here is we need to check the partner with multiple **if else** condition and then validate the user.

I know we can use the Polymorphism with this and can be achieved by **Interface** as follows

```
interface ValidateUser {
    public function validate();
}

class Partner1 implements ValidateUser{
    public function validate(){

    }
}
```

But again I need to check and create the partner object and the following code still exists

```
$partnerObj = new Partner1();
$partnerObj->validate($phone);
```

I had read somewhere that we can pass directly the interface object to achieve this without the object knowledge. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Any other programming language implementation with **Interface** or similar feature of PHP is welcome.

Comment: Does you method `getPartnerDetailsByUniqueId();` returns one of the `partner1`, `partner2` or `partner3` only?

Comment: @Zeusarm I mean yes it returns any valid Partner based on the column **unique_id**

Comment: But do you have the appropriate class for each type of partner?

Comment: No, I don't as its just a **single validation class**. But will be implementing soon this way.  Or else I will change it to the existing way.

Comment: maybe you could use it in this way? `$partner = ucwords($partner);$partnerObj = new $partner();`

Comment: @Zeusarm I have updated my code to validate. Earlier even I had thought the same. But the problem is Today we are having 7 to 8 Partners but down the line in 2 months we may have 70 to 80 partners. Which I dont think feasible to create classes

Comment: @Zeusarm any other thing that can be incorporated with the same. Thank you very much for your blazing fast reply

Comment: you mean in the future there will be some partner types which will correspond to the same class?

Comment: @Zeusarm yes there will be only class which will have **validatePartner1** **validatePartner2** functions and so on. Is there any other way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing interface having simple function validate.

```
class partnerFactory {
    public static function getType($type) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'partner1':
               return new Partner1();
            case 'partner2':
               return new Partner1();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Partner1 implements ValidateUser {
    public function validate() {
        // your function here.
    }
}

interface ValidateUser {
    public function validate() { }
}

$partner1 = partnerFactory::getType('partner1');
$partner1->validate();

$partner2 = partnerFactory::getType('partner2');
$partner2->validate();
```